# Using TERADATA: Running simple SELECT DISTINCT and getting SPOOL SPACE ERROR

Tags: teradata

I am new to Teradata and am a bit confused. I've Googled and searched here and am still uncertain as to why.  Hoping to find some clarity here.

I have two queries:

```
SELECT distinct foo FROM table.A; 

SELECT distinct foo2 FROM table.A;
```

Neither attribute appears to be keys.

One produces desired results; the other does not.  I keep getting a spool space error.

I ran explain plans on both and they have similar execution times and row counts.

Any suggestions as to why this is occurring?

Comment: First guess would be stats.  Do you have current statistics on one column but not the other?

Comment: "No statistics exist on this table"  ?

wait..stand by.  running on the attributes now.

and, fail - no go since no statistics on object as a whole. derf.

Comment: The optimizer probably chooses a bad plan due to non-existing stats, what does Explain show `aggregated` or `sort removing duplicate rows`, probably #2? How many rows exist in that table and how many distinct values, is there a default?

Comment: Both plans' steps in the same order.

+ all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate by way of an all-rows scan with no residual conditions  
+ all-AMPs RETRIEVE step by way of an all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool XX (all_amps)(compressed columns allowed), which is duplicated on all AMPs.    
+ a SORT to partition by rowkey. 
+ a SORT to order Spool XX by the hash code 
+ a SORT to order Spool XX by row hash
+ a SORT to order Spool XX by the hash code

Comment: (sorry, trying to format the list...dafu...q)

Comment: The object currently has 165,074,325 rows.  

I have no idea how many distinct values, that's one of the things I am trying to find out.   

There are no defaults on the object.

Comment: Is this running against a table or a view? What does a `SHOW SELECT distinct foo ...` return?

Comment: It's running against a view.  Both SHOW(s) have 18 CREATE SET TABLE(s).    The one difference I see is this: 

Replace view AS: 

Foo1:  LOCK ROW FOR ACCESS
Foo:    LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS

Would that do it?

Comment: Then it's not a *simple distinct*, it has to perform all those joins *first* and then apply the Distinct on top of it. Depending on what you need you might simply run a Distinct against the base table where this column is coming from.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you for walking me through this.